# Bookshelf- how to order by relation

Tags: bookshelf.js

```
` new RevisionModel()
    .query('where', 'bbid', '=', req.params.bbid)
    .fetchPage({
        limit: size,
        offset: from,
        withRelated: ['revision']
    });`
```

I want to sort the results according to `revision.created_at`. How do I achieve it?

This is how my RevisionModel is created.

```
`bookshelf.Model.extend({
///
    revision() {
        return this.belongsTo('Revision', 'id');
    },
///
});`
```

Comment: This is very confusing. The model is called `RevisionModel` but then there's another relationship with something else called `Revision`?

Comment: Well actually there are 5 types of models- `authorRevision`, `publisherRevision`, etc. Each of them are related to Revision. There is a function which takes one of these 5 models as argument and just to keep it generic, it's named as `RevisionModel`

Comment: Anyway you got my query right? I want to sort according to `revision.created_at`